# How to organize classes to share data members but preserve encapsulation c++?

Tags: c++, tree, encapsulation

I want to build a tree breadth first in c++ using a queue.  I have the files Queue.h, Queue.cpp, Tree.h, Tree.cpp, and main.cpp.  My main class #includes "Tree.cpp".  How do I structure these files using the #include keyword so that my Queue can push and pop tree nodes, and my tree can manipulate the Queue?  It seems that part of the problem I am having is that the struct in each class is private.  My Queue cannot define a treePtr in its struct, and my tree cannot instantiate new queue nodes.  Should I make the structs in each class public so they can access each other across classes?  In general, how am I suppose to organize these classes to make use of encapsulation?

```
class Tree{
private:
    typedef struct tree {
        int data;
        tree* left;
        tree* right;
    }* treePtr;

    treePtr root;
    int numNodes;
    void addTree(int n, treePtr child);
    treePtr addTree(int n);


public:

    Tree();
    void addTreeNode(int integer);
    treePtr getRoot();
    void printTreeNode(int n, treePtr treeRoot);

};


class Queue {
private:
    typedef struct node {
        Tree::treePtr treeNode;
        node* next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr current;

public:
    Queue();
    void push(treePtr t);
    int pop();
};
```

Comment: Make Tree and Queue mutual friends.

Comment: I think this got me on the right track.  Please answer my question so I can give you a check.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Eugene, the answer is to make Tree and Queue mutual friends.  This is done in the header files for each class inside the class body.